# Removing Patterns in sed with n characters

Tags: unix, sed

I'm faced with a situation where I need to remove all instances of "The" from a file globally, but not instances of "Then" or "There".

So far I have tried to replace all the "The" instances but limit it to 3 characters.

```
sed -e s'/The\{3}//g'
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Comment: `/The\{3}/` will match `Theee`.

Comment: You want `/The\b/` or `/The\>/` to match word boundaries.

Comment: @Zulu Yes, It doesn't let me parse.

Comment: @EtanReisner How do I use the syntax for 3 characters?

Comment: people get hung up using extra reg-ex features. You can accomplish what you want with `sed 's/The / /g'`, right? Note the space char after `e` and that we just replace the 4 char match with 1 char of space. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter That will not match a sentence that ends with `The.` or a `The` at the end of a line/the file.

Comment: Like I said, `\{3}` matches that many of the previous item. `/The/` is three items. You *might* be able to use `/(The)\{3}/` in some engines to match `TheTheThe`.

Comment: `sed 's/The / /g;s/The$//.` will fix `The` at the end of a line. I would consider a sentence ending in `The.` to be out of scope. I'll leave fixing that case as an opportunity for learning to the O.P. by extending these examples. good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kmariappan `$ sed 's/\bthe\b/in/g' filename`

that command will do what you need